# LEFT JOIN in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

My (abbreviated) Code is:

```
SELECT *

FROM
ASSESSMENT A
LEFT JOIN FINANCE F0 
ON F0.CLIENT = A.CLIENT
AND F0.FIELD_CODE = 1
AND F0.EVNT_SQNBR =
      (SELECT MAX(FX.EVNT_SQNBR)
      FROM
      FINANCE FX, CROSSREF Y
      WHERE
           Y.CLIENT        = A.CLIENT
       AND Y.ASMT_TCD      = A.ASMT_TCD
       AND Y.ASMT_TY_SQNBR = A.ASMT_TY_SQNBR
       AND FX.CLIENT_ID    = A.CLIENT
       AND FX.FIELD_CODE   = F0.FIELD_CODE
       AND FX.BUS_LN_SQNBR = F0.BUS_LN_SQNBR
       AND FX.EVNT_SQNBR   = Y.EVNT_SQNBR)

LEFT JOIN FINANCE F1 (SAME CODE HERE EXCEPT F1.FIELD_CODE IS DIFFERENT)
...
LEFT JOIN FINANCE F2 (SAME CODE HERE EXCEPT F2.FIELD_CODE IS DIFFERENT)
```

And so on.

The question is it gives -338 ON Clause is Invalid. For all lines (inclusive) starting with AND F0.EVNT_SQNBR = ...

Any idea why, and how to fix it?

Comment: You cannot have a sub-select in the `ON` clause. Consider moving it to the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: If you move it to the WHERE clause, doesn't it become an implicit INNER JOIN? I need an OUTER JOIN.

Comment: That depends on _how_ you do it, doesn't it. What other options do you have?

Comment: Any pointers? I cant see how else to do this without radically changing the format, which I would prefer not to do.

Comment: `WHERE F0.EVNT_SQNBR = (SELECT MAX...) OR F0.EVNT_SQNBR IS NULL` should do the trick, no?

Comment: You might be able to vastly simplify the whole thing by extracting a CTE, which you could then join to.  For that matter, the whole thing looks like it should be some form of regular aggregation-and-join.  Sample data and desired results would help, though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this I guess...

```
WITH MAXES AS
(
  SELECT FX.CLIENT_ID, FX.FIELD_CODE, FX.BUS_LN_SQNBR, FX.EVNT_SQNBR, Y.ASMT_TCD, Y.ASMT_TY_SQNBR, MAX(FX.EVNT_SQNBR) AS THEMAX
  FROM FINANCE FX
  JOIN CROSSREF Y ON FX.CLIENT_ID = Y.CLIENT AND FX.EVNT_SQNBR = Y.EVNT_SQNBR
  GROUP BY   
    FX.CLIENT_ID   ,
    FX.FIELD_CODE  ,
    FX.BUS_LN_SQNBR,
    FX.EVNT_SQNBR,
    Y.ASMT_TCD,
    Y.ASMT_TY_SQNBR
)
SELECT *
FROM ASSESSMENT A
LEFT JOIN FINANCE F0 ON F0.CLIENT = A.CLIENT AND F0.FIELD_CODE = 1 
LEFT JOIN MAXES M0 ON (M0.THEMAX, M0.ASMT_TCD,  M0.ASMT_TY_SQNBR, M0.CLIENT_ID, M0.FIELD_CODE, M0.BUS_LN_SQNBR) = (F0.EVNT_SQNBR, A.ASMT_TCD, A.ASMT_TY_SQNBR, A.CLIENT, F0.FIELD_CODE, F0.BUS_LN_SQNBR)
LEFT JOIN FINANCE F1 ON F1.CLIENT = A.CLIENT AND F1.FIELD_CODE = 2 
LEFT JOIN MAXES M1 ON (M1.THEMAX, M1.ASMT_TCD,  M1.ASMT_TY_SQNBR, M1.CLIENT_ID, M1.FIELD_CODE, M1.BUS_LN_SQNBR) = (F1.EVNT_SQNBR, A.ASMT_TCD, A.ASMT_TY_SQNBR, A.CLIENT, F0.FIELD_CODE, F1.BUS_LN_SQNBR)
LEFT JOIN FINANCE F2 ON F2.CLIENT = A.CLIENT AND F2.FIELD_CODE = 3 
LEFT JOIN MAXES M2 ON (M2.THEMAX, M2.ASMT_TCD,  M2.ASMT_TY_SQNBR, M2.CLIENT_ID, M2.FIELD_CODE, M2.BUS_LN_SQNBR) = (F2.EVNT_SQNBR, A.ASMT_TCD, A.ASMT_TY_SQNBR, A.CLIENT, F0.FIELD_CODE, F2.BUS_LN_SQNBR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The qualifier FN0 does not exist in the JOIN SQL Statement. I think you meant F0.

```
AND FX.FIELD_CODE   = F0.FIELD_CODE
AND FX.BUS_LN_SQNBR = F0.BUS_LN_SQNBR
```

Comment: Yeah.. a copying mistake, its actually F0. Fixed.

Comment: What will your results look like?

Comment: Well, its a very big SPUFI, so I just submitted an abbreviated code snippet. Something like Client, FieldCode1Value, FieldCode2Value, ... FieldCode9Value, OtherFieldsFromNotShownTablesNotPartofJoin